# R Fill NAs dependent on value after NAs and how many NAs there are

Tags: r, na, missing-data

Hi I want to fill the NAs in my data.frame based on both the first number after the NAs and how many NAs there are. It is rainfall data and the NAs show times that the gauge wasn't communicating but we know the total rain that occurred in that period and want to average across it.

There are a lot of questions on here about how to fill them but I haven't found any that need to use the number of NAs. Basically I want to average the value of the number after the NAs by the number of timesteps missing.

Here is my example data. I've made it very simple but in real example I have hundreds of thousands of entries and will be grouping data by site.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo) 
testdf <- data.frame(DateTime = seq.POSIXt(
  from = as.POSIXct("2019-01-01"), to =  as.POSIXct("2019-01-02"), by = "hours"),
  Value = c(0,0,1,NA,NA,NA,-4,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-2,5,3,NA,-2,0,0,0,1,2))
```

I can easily fill the NAs with the first value after using either `tidyr::fill` or `zoo:na.locf`:

```
tidyr::fill(testdf,Value, .direction = "up")

testdf %>% mutate(Filled = zoo::na.locf(Value, fromLast = T))
```

But I want to divide this by how many NAs were occurring in a row plus 1 (i.e if there are 5 NAs divide by 6). Ideally I'd also like to change the value after the NAs to also equal this new value, but I can probably hack something for this step if necessary.

Bonus points if there is an easy way to only do this for gaps of certain periods (basically the maxgap feature of na.locf) as if I have an hour or two missing its okay to average but if it is a week or month I want to leave it as NA.

Example Output

```
desiredOutput <- data.frame(DateTime = seq.POSIXt(
  from = as.POSIXct("2019-01-01"), to =  as.POSIXct("2019-01-02"), by = "hours"),
  Value = c(0,0,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,-0.33,-0.33,-0.33,-0.33,-0.33,-0.33,5,3,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`. Grouped by the `shift`ed cumulative sum of logical vector of non-NA elements in 'Value', divide the `last` 'Value' with the number of rows and assign (`:=`) to update the 'Value' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(testdf)[,  Value := last(Value)/.N, shift(cumsum(!is.na(Value)), fill = 1)]
testdf
#               DateTime      Value
# 1: 2019-01-01 00:00:00  0.0000000
# 2: 2019-01-01 01:00:00  0.0000000
# 3: 2019-01-01 02:00:00  1.0000000
# 4: 2019-01-01 03:00:00 -1.0000000
# 5: 2019-01-01 04:00:00 -1.0000000
# 6: 2019-01-01 05:00:00 -1.0000000
# 7: 2019-01-01 06:00:00 -1.0000000
# 8: 2019-01-01 07:00:00  0.0000000
# 9: 2019-01-01 08:00:00  0.0000000
#10: 2019-01-01 09:00:00  0.0000000
#11: 2019-01-01 10:00:00 -0.3333333
#12: 2019-01-01 11:00:00 -0.3333333
#13: 2019-01-01 12:00:00 -0.3333333
#14: 2019-01-01 13:00:00 -0.3333333
#15: 2019-01-01 14:00:00 -0.3333333
#16: 2019-01-01 15:00:00 -0.3333333
#17: 2019-01-01 16:00:00  5.0000000
#18: 2019-01-01 17:00:00  3.0000000
#9: 2019-01-01 18:00:00 -1.0000000
#20: 2019-01-01 19:00:00 -1.0000000
#21: 2019-01-01 20:00:00  0.0000000
#22: 2019-01-01 21:00:00  0.0000000
#23: 2019-01-01 22:00:00  0.0000000
#24: 2019-01-01 23:00:00  1.0000000
#25: 2019-01-02 00:00:00  2.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks really good and I'm guessing is faster than the `dplyr` response below. I am however much more comfortable with `dplyr` than `data.table`. To include a max number of timesteps to change would changing `Value := last(Value)/.N` to `Value := ifelse(.N > 5,NA_real_,last(Value)/.N)` be appropriate? Or is there a more `data.table` friendly method?

Answer (score 2):

One way using `dplyr` could be to create group such that the first non-NA value after consecutive `NA`s is included in the group so that we can just take the `last(Value)` and divide it by number of rows in the group (`n()`). The non-NA's value are stored in their individual group with only one element so the calculation for them is not affected and non-NA number return the same number.

```
library(dplyr)

testdf %>%
   group_by(group = lag(cumsum(!is.na(Value)), default = 1)) %>%
   mutate(Value = last(Value)/n()) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-group)

# A tibble: 25 x 2
#   DateTime            Value
#   <dttm>              <dbl>
# 1 2019-01-01 00:00:00     0
# 2 2019-01-01 01:00:00     0
# 3 2019-01-01 02:00:00     1
# 4 2019-01-01 03:00:00    -1
# 5 2019-01-01 04:00:00    -1
# 6 2019-01-01 05:00:00    -1
# 7 2019-01-01 06:00:00    -1
# 8 2019-01-01 07:00:00     0
# 9 2019-01-01 08:00:00     0
#10 2019-01-01 09:00:00     0
# … with 15 more rows
```

To include the `maxgap` feature we can subtract the last `Datetime` with the first one and if it is greater than certain value `replace` it with `NA`, for example below I have done for 10 hour duration.

```
testdf %>%
   group_by(group = lag(cumsum(!is.na(Value)), default = 1)) %>%
   mutate(Value = last(Value)/n(), 
          Value = replace(Value, as.integer(difftime(DateTime[max(n() - 1, 1)],
                  first(DateTime), units = "hours")) > 10, NA))
```

Comment: Thanks, these both look like great answers and work well on the sample. I haven't had a chance to try on my full data set so will hold off confirming an answer until then

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I think I will use it in future, but with my current data with > 3 million data points I went with the data.table as its faster, but yours works exactly as I'd hoped, just grouping almost all records line by line equal very slow calculation!

Answer (score 0):

Might be hard to adapt this to the quite specific details here, but in general the `na_ma` moving average imputation function from the `imputeTS` package can help you to replace your NAs with the average of the non-NA values around the missing value. It also has the required `maxgap` option.

You can just call

```
library("imputeTS")
na_ma(x, k = 4, weighting = "simple", maxgap = 5)
```

This will replace the NA value with the average of the closest 4 values (4 to the left, 4 to the right). With maxgap = 5 you define, that consecutive NAs runs, that are longer than 5 will be left NA.